# rails migration failing silently

Tags: activerecord, migration

I've never had anything but success w/ Rails migrations, so this one is especially perplexing to me.  I have a migration that I just wrote, it's fairly simple, but when I try and run it (for the first time, or after rolling back and trying again), there is no output to the console for a few seconds, the job ends, and no change has occurred to my DB, other than checking rake db:migrate:status will show the migration has run (or, it thinks it has).

Migration code is here:

```
class AddNotesToCases < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
      add_column :cases, :notes, :text
    end

    def down
      remove_column :cases, :notes
    end
  end
```

db is PostGres, Rails is 3.0.9, rake is 0.9.2.2

EDIT **
per request, the results of a trace on the rake call are:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

FWIW, I also have tried rewriting the migration to use a String instead of Text datatype, and also have tried using the def change rather than up/down.  No joy on any of them.

Comment: Have you checked for the migration's timestamp in the `schema_migrations` table? You could also roll it back and try again with `rake -t db:migrate` to get a trace of the run.

Comment: Yes, timestamp is in the schema_migrations table. I did the trace (before; and just now again at your suggestion) and have put the results in the question

Comment: Your migration is connecting to the right database, right? Shots in the dark: toss a `puts` in your `up` method, do a `connection.execute(some_sql)` to directly modify something in your database through SQL, do a `connection.select_rows` to directly extract something from your database in your `up` method and `puts` it to see if you get what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, ok, after re-generating the file from scratch I realized when going from the `change` version to the up/down version, I'd typeoed the methods and forgot the 'self' on them.  :|

```
def self.up
```

worked where my code didn't.

Comment: +1 for owning up to it. I've been using 3.2 where both `def up` and `def self.up` are supported so I didn't think of that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The author must have been using  Rails version prior to 3.1 because after that [singleton methods were no longer needed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/68b66ef308).